# how to change a class method behavior and output in php

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, frameworks, template-engine

How can I design a pattern that can affect calling methods of a class and getting an output from them, for example when we use `return $this` we can constantly call multiple methods using pointers but in this approach, we cant affect the previous called method through the last called method..

Instance code :

```
layout1.php
|--------------|
<div>

 {content}

</div>


index.php 
|-----------|

//return output
$view->layout('layout1')->content('test');
```

In case the instance code changed to the following

```
//echo output
$view->layout('layout1');
```

I need the function to be informed and show a different behavior on sending the output. For instance , in the first code the output value should be returned but in the second one, the value must be directly echoed..

**Sample code :**

```
layout1.php
|--------------|
<div>

{content}

</div>


index.php 
|-----------|

$view = view();

//return output
$view->layout('layout1')->content('test');


//echo output
$view->layout('layout1');



 view.php
|-----------|

class view{

 public function layout($file){

  return $this;
 }


 public function content($html){

 return $this;
 }

}
```

**Thank you very much in advance for your help...**

Answer (score 0):

Hi It's actually impossible to change the chain call rule. 
What you can do is to change the approach

```
$view->content('test')->layout('layout1');
```

As your problem solved :)

OR

```
class view{

 public function layout($file){

  return $this;
 }


 public function content($html){

 return $this;
 }
public function __toString(){
return $vars; // in a string format
}
```

and

```
echo $view->layout('layout1'); // will echo the result
$view->layout('layout1')->content('test'); // return result
```

}

Comment: How to return $view->layout('layout1'); to variable?